# Application written in Visual Studio 2017 does not run/open in Windows 7 Machine

Tags: visual-studio-2017, mfc, windows-7-x64

[image]I have an MFC application developed in Visual studio 2017 (Windows 10). When i tried to install the application in Windows 7 machine it does not open/run. I tried to install updates needed for windows 7 as suggested in https://support.microsoft.com/en-in/help/3118401/update-for-universal-c-runtime-in-windows but it does not help. Is there anything else that is missing

Comment: Probably you have created with GUI elements that are not available in Windows 7 in my opinion.

Comment: But is your MFC project using shared resources or static? The default is shared. In which case you have to ensure the MFC Runtimes are installed on the target computer.

Comment: You should download Microsoft Visual C++ 2017 Redistributable from the [link](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/zh-hans/downloads/?rr=https%3A%2F%2Fsocial.msdn.microsoft.com%2FForums%2Fvstudio%2Fen-US%2Fe653a57a-bc32-4134-87bf-df33058f0531%2Fdownload-microsoft-visual-c-2017-redistributable%3Fforum%3Dvssetup) 
Visual C++ 2015, 2017 and 2019 all share the same redistributable files

Comment: _It does not run_: is there an error message?

Comment: @Jabberwocky: No, It just doesn't open and hang on

Comment: @Jeaninez-MSFT: I did install the Redistributable but it did not help me

Comment: What's the _Platform Toolset_, the _Target Platform Version_ and the _Use of MFC_ (Project-Properties, Configuration Properties->General)?

Comment: When you _install_, (how do you do that?), on a 10 machine without VS, it works? I'm deploying from VS2019, SDK 10 latest version, to several 7 machines fine. You have a mystery that needs more info. I suspect it is something about how you are deploying, running, on a target machine.

Comment: In a Japanese article two months ago, there was a problem with a dll built in debug mode. Is there such a thing? [Visual Studioで作成したアプリが別のPCで動作しない](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/57271/26370) Or are you using APIs that are not in Windows 7 but in Windows 10?

Comment: @Jabberwocky: I have added the details to the original post

Comment: @lakeweb: Yes it works even without installing visual studio. I suspect that it has something do with using CRuntime libraries

Comment: @SandeepKumar Try setting _Use of MFC_ to _Use MFC in a Static Library_

Comment: @Jabberwocky: I tried this earlier and i get this error  "  C1189: #error:  Building MFC application with /MD[d] (CRT dll version) requires MFC shared dll version. Please #define _AFXDLL or do not use /MD[d] "

Comment: @SandeepKumar then [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/windows/redistributing-the-mfc-library?view=vs-2019) might be interesting.

Comment: you want [vc_redist.x86.exe](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2977003/the-latest-supported-visual-c-downloads). But if that were the issue, you would get a missing dll message, so I wouldn't be looking there. You did not say how you are installing. If you are just copying the exe to the computer and running without permission to write the registry, well... The very next thing to do is start a std::ofstream right up at the start and log with std::endl on the lines. See if you even create the file.

Comment: @Jabberwocky: It was informative but did not help me. One thing i observed is, the application basically crashes when i tried to use any C function like memset, memcpy etc. from the file vcruntime_string.h. It works fine with visual studio 2017(windows 10) and same thing crashes visual studio 2017(windows 7) and in both the machines the path of the file is same ( C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017 15.9\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\include)

Comment: You want to use Visual Studio 2017 on Win 7 OS, the preconditions is required [KB3151802](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=53345) to install.And then [Update for Universal C Runtime in Windows](https://support.microsoft.com/en-sg/help/2999226/update-for-universal-c-runtime-in-windows)

Comment: @Jeaninez-MSFT: I tried these before but it did not help me solve the issue.